# Windows 10 Docker Build Error: "error from sender: open LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup: Access is denied."

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, windows-10, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Docker image for a Python project on a 64-bit Windows 10 console. I have Docker version 20.10.7 installed with a WSL2-based engine and Ubuntu-18.04 integration.

The Dockerfile structure is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8.10

MAINTAINER 

WORKDIR ./VoiceRecognition

COPY ./ .


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ .

ENTRYPOINT [ 'python3' ]

CMD [ 'VoiceRecognition/RunSpeakerIdentitification.py' ]
```

And I'm attempting to perform the build operation with the following command in Windows Powershell:

`docker build -t voice-recognition:v1 -f ./VoiceRecognition/Dockerfile .`

Running Powershell as an administrator provides the following error:

```
=> ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                            3.1s
 => => transferring context: 114.79MB                                                                              3.1s
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error from sender: open LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup: Access is denied.
```

I've scoured forums searching for a potential solution, but all of the troubleshooting methods for related issues don't seem to work. I have edited group permissions as explained [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/868) and tried calling `docker login` before the build command. Additionally, running Powershell as a non-administrator throws this (different) error:

```
=> ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                           47.6s
 => => transferring context: 1.42GB                                                                               47.6s
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error from sender: open AppData\Local\ElevatedDiagnostics: Access is denied.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I just had this. My working folder was quite deep so I thought I might be hitting some [path length issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd). I tried moving it to the root of my C drive and I no longer had this issue. Perhaps give that a go?

Comment: Did you have the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue just now. Oddly, it was fixed when I changed directory one level up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I don't have a great solution I'll tell you what worked for me:

I always use linux, but I wanted to try docker on windows so I did the same steps the same configuration in my app and it failed. I don't know why this error was generated:

error from sender: open env\lib64: Access is denied.

Then install linux bash on windows and it worked.